# Symfony : How to create Multiple RadioBoxes using the form Builder

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I'm working on a new project where i was asked to create this type of form :

[image]

I have created an entity with a json_array attribute that stores this form 
configuration. 
example :

```
{
   "DescenteCde" : 0 // checked radiobutton is "Aucun"
   "WebShopPC" : 1 // checked radiobutton is "Faible"
}
```

I want to know the easiest way to generate this type of form using the symfony form builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. Actually, Symfony framework provides us with A Collection Type that takes a array as a parameter and then we specify the different options and values/

```
  $ImpactApplicationFormBuilder->add('***Configuration***',CollectionType::class, array(
      'entry_type'   => ChoiceType::class,
      'entry_options'  => array(
   'choices'  => array(
     'Aucun' => 0,
     'Faible' => 1,
     'Moyen' => 2,
     'Fort'=> 3
   ),
   'multiple' => false,
   "expanded" => true ,
  ),
));
```

Configuration attibute is of type array so in the form the different keys of your array will be rendered with the given options you provided.

Your result will look like this :

[image]

Hope this help anybody with the same problem